# Unable to create a new data source to SQL Server through ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-express

I'm new to SQL Server. I'm trying to create a new data source through ODBC Data Source Administrator for accessing a SQL Server database file (`.mdf`).

I first experienced an error msg

> [TCP/IP Sockets]Specified SQL server not found

when running SQL Server ODBC Data Source Test.

After following all the steps in http://www.ceus-now.com/how-to-connect-to-ms-sql-express/, the previous error msg disappears and the tests are successful.

The connection seems to be successful. But then I experienced another problem is that, I could not choose the database. According to https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1471/sql-server-dsn-and-odbc-configuration/ .

The problem might be "If using Windows security, you as the DSN creator, do not have rights to the database". Could someone help me solve this problem please? I really appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

I'm using Windows NT authentication. I'm using SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.2000). SQL Server connect to `WORKSTATIONNAME/SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: When installing SQL Express Server what Authentication mode did you enable (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143705%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)? Also have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx

Comment: Thank you Alex! The Authentication mode is Windows authentication when installing SQL. I followed the steps you provided in the second link, using SSMS, I found trouble to create the new database user with "Windows User" option. Do you know how to fill those out?

Comment: I chose "Windows User" as User Type, "DOMAIN\user1" as User Name, "DOMAIN\user1" as Login Name, "dbo" as Default Schema. This created the error.